# when switching months, I want to stop fullcalendar from removing events

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, fullcalendar

Passing fullCalendar an array of events ensures that those events do not get removed when switching months.

But let's say you load events not by month, but by something else. For instance, say you want to load all of a users events on the year. Let's also say that you can dynamically add users after the page is loaded.

Now that there are dynamically loaded events fullCalendar tends to remove events every time you switch months.

How can I force fullCalendar to let *me* handle **when** and **which** events get removed?

**Edit** I kind of feel I'm missing something pretty fundamental in the documentation. But for the life of me I haven't seen anything in the docs to stop fullCalendar from removing events.

What I currently have:

```
// Initialize the calendar
$('#calendar').fullCalendar();

// Represents a list of all the events currently on the calendar
this.events = new Backbone.Collection();

// Add and removal events for this collection
this.events.on('add', function( ev ) {
    // We need to check to make sure the calendar is initialized
    if ( $('#calendar').children().length > 0 ) {
        // Calendar is initialized, let's add our event
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', ev.attributes );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaaand I found what I was missing in the documentation!

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/